# Polynomial regression in SAS macro

Tags: arrays, macros, sas

I have a dataset on of month v.s temperature and I want to write a macro that performs polynomial regression for me. And the order of the polynomial is the input parameter. So if I were to call the macro `%polyreg(3)` I expect `model temp=month month**2 month**3` to be used to fit the model. I'm having trouble with how to incorporate that into my macro.

```
%macro polyreg(order);
proc reg data=mydata;
model temp=month**&order; *this will not work because if I were to call %polyreg(3), then the model would only be temp=month**3*
run;
%mend;
```

So I'm thinking of using an array, but that didn't seem to work out...

```
%macro polyreg(order);
array var{&order} month**1--month**&order;
proc reg data=mydata;
model temp=var{&order};
run;
%mend;
```

How can I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation!  This says that you cannot use quadratic terms directly in the MODEL statement.  What you need to do is add the values as separate variables into the dataset and then reference those in PROC REG.  You may as well add as many as you think you need, so they are all available to select in the regression.

What I would is rename month to something like month_1, then the square is month_2, cube is month_3 etc.  Then you can use your macro to select whichever order you want.  See the code below for an example.

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;
rename age=age_1;
age_2 = age**2;
age_3 = age**3;
run;

%macro polyreg(order);
proc reg data=class;
model height = age_1-age_&order;
run;
%mend polyreg;

%polyreg(2);
```